# How to enable LDAP on a dockerized Wordpress?

Tags: php, docker, ldap

I have this container that I ran with a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:

    db:
     <...>

    wordpress:
      depends_on:
        - db
      image: wordpress:latest
      ports:
        - "8000:80"
      restart: always
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

I need to [enable LDAP on PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php) but I really can't find out how to complete the steps explained in the tutorial.

> You will need to use the **--with-ldap[=DIR]** configuration option when
>   compiling PHP to enable LDAP support.

How am I supposed to do this on a running container ? Should this be done before running `docker-compose up` if so, which environment configuration am I supposed to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use a different image as it's not easily configurable using the original image.

Have a look at [dalareo/docker-wordpress-ldap-support](https://github.com/dalareo/docker-wordpress-ldap-support) on GitHub. You might use this Dockerfile by downloading it to the directory your project would be stored in and make a small change to your docker-compose.yml like here:

```
version: '3'
services:

    db:
     <...>

    wordpress:
      depends_on:
        - db
      # remove: image: wordpress:latest and put this instead:
      build: .
      # and place the rest of the definitions you normally have there
```

The Dockerfile copied from the repo:

```
FROM wordpress

RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libldap2-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove libldap2-dev
```

**edit**

I've found a public registry image build from this Dockerfile

Now you don't actually have to make any changes to your original docker-compose.yml file except for changing the image your wordpress is expected to run from. From `wordpress:latest` to `dalareo/wordpress-ldap`

Comment: I guess this is it .. I thought there would be a way to do it with the original image, but I think I'm too new to Docker to handle this. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Actually it's a PHP/Wordpress issue that it's not easily configurable because this parameter you provided in the question is not injectable to the image command. That's why it's just better to use a different image (but this image I linked is based on the official image, and only making changes on the way)